# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

i write this simple login code in node.js :

```
var express = require ("express");
var badyparser = require ("body-parser");

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/static"));
app.use(badyparser());

var users = {
  tom : "1",
  jenny : "12",
  mary : "123"
};

app.get("/" , function(req,resp,next){
  resp.sendFile(__dirname + "/static/home.html")
});

app.post("/login" ,  function(req , resp , next){
//  console.log(req.body);  // print in terminal
//  console.log(users);
  for (user in users) {
    if (req.body['username'] == user){
      if (req.body['password'] == users[user]){
        resp.json({status : "true" , msg : "YES"});
        console.log("YES");
      }
      else {
        resp.json({status : "false" , msg : "password is false"});
        console.log("password is false");
      }
    }
    else {
      resp.json({status : "false" , msg : "user not found"});
      console.log("user not found");
    }
  }

} );

app.listen(8000);
console.log("port open");
```

in browser page show correct answer but in terminal show this error :

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:494:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:501:3)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/mohammad/Desktop/test/Login/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/mohammad/Desktop/test/Login/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/Users/mohammad/Desktop/test/Login/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
    at /Users/mohammad/Desktop/test/Login/server.js:36:8
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/mohammad/Desktop/test/Login/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/mohammad/Desktop/test/Login/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/mohammad/Desktop/test/Login/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/mohammad/Desktop/test/Login/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)

(i am New in node)
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only a single .send() or .json() per route. The error you get is from the second time .json is called.

To fix it, just place a return after each call.

Answer (score 0):

The **resp** object in `app.post("/login" ,  function(req , resp , next){})` is an object of http.ServerResponse https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse.

You can set your header using `resp.setHeader(name, value)` until you send `resp.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });` Once `resp.writeHead()` is called, you can no longer set any header again except `res.end('Your content');`. This is because the client will continue to wait for a response from your server until a response body is received or the timeout occurs. And once a response body is received, you can't set any other header.

You get the error **Can't set headers after they are sent. at validateHeader** because the below snippet that you used send the response body more than once which is not acceptable.

```
 for (user in users) {
    if (req.body['username'] == user){
      if (req.body['password'] == users[user]){
        resp.json({status : "true" , msg : "YES"});
        console.log("YES");
      }
      else {
        resp.json({status : "false" , msg : "password is false"});
        console.log("password is false");
      }
    }
    else {
      resp.json({status : "false" , msg : "user not found"});
      console.log("user not found");
    }
  }
```

Instead of the above, you can store all your objects in an array and return it once.

```
 var returnableObject = [];

 for (user in users) {

    if (req.body['username'] == user){
      if (req.body['password'] == users[user]){
        returnableObject.push({status : "true" , msg : "YES"});
        console.log("YES");
      }
      else {
        returnableObject.push({status : "false" , msg : "password is false"});
        console.log("password is false");
      }
    }
    else {
      returnableObject.push({status : "false" , msg : "user not found"});
      console.log("user not found");
    }

  }

  resp.json(returnableObject);
```